# Display list on page or in drawer menu depending on screen width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, react-spring

I have a menu that displays as a hamburger/drawer menu when screen width is less than a certain amount and I am using react-spring to slide that menu on-screen when the "hamburger icon" is clicked. My issue is that the `<ul>` is within that `<animated.div>` from react-springs so when the screen size is wider and the hamburger/drawer menu is hidden, the `<ul>` with the list items are hidden with it, which I do not want, I want the menu to be displayed normally on page (without a drawer) when the screen is wider. Is there a way to achieve this without having to create two `<ul>`'s with the same `<li>`'s twice, one within the `<animated.div>` that displays in a drawer menu on narrower screens and one that displays on page on wider screens?

React.js/JSX:

```
return (
    //State of menuVisible starts off as false
    <FontAwesomeIcon
      className="menuBarIcon"
      icon={faBars}
      onClick={() => setMenuVisible(!menuVisible)}/>
    {menuTransitions(
      (styles, item) => item &&
      <animated.div
        style={styles}
        className="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a>Menu Item One</a></li>
          <li><a>Menu Item Two</a></li>
          <li><a>Menu Item Three</a></li>
          <li><a>Menu Item Four</a></li>
          <li><a>Menu Item Five</a></li>
        </ul>
      </animated.div>
    )}
);
```

CSS:

```
//Wider screens
.menuBarIcon {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1080px) {
//Narrower screens
.menuBarIcon {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 25px;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 320px;
  height: 100%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, what I did was to first have the `<ul>` outside of the `<animated.div>` so that now it displays normally in wider screens. I then added a ternary operator to the `<ul>` based on the state of `menuVisible` so that it would alternate between two classes, one that would hide the `<ul>` and one that would display it. Then to have it positioned within the drawer menu I simply added the CSS of the `menu` class to the `<ul>` in the media query for narrower screens.

React.js/JSX:

```
return (
<FontAwesomeIcon
  className="menuBarIcon"
  icon={faBars}
  onClick={() => setMenuVisible(!menuVisible)}/>
{menuTransitions(
  (styles, item) => item &&
  <animated.div
    style={styles}
    className="menu">
  </animated.div>
)}
//Class alternates between the two based on condition of the state of menuVisible
<ul className={menuVisible ? "menuActive" : "menuInactive"}>
  <li><a>Menu Item One</a></li>
  <li><a>Menu Item Two</a></li>
  <li><a>Menu Item Three</a></li>
  <li><a>Menu Item Four</a></li>
  <li><a>Menu Item Five</a></li>
</ul>
);
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 1080px) {
//Narrower screens

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 320px;
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  //Added same CSS as .menu class to Ul to position the list within the drawer menu
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 280px; //width is different to compensate for padding in li
  height: 100%
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menuActive {
  //Ul displays normally when menuVisible state is true
  display: block;
}

.menuInactive {
  //Ul is hidden when menuVisible state is false
  display: none;
}
}
```